# Кто "прислуживает" боксёру на ринге?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Средняя дочь беспрекословно приняла и его, **как полотенце боксёра –
>   служка в тренерском углу**, и теперь тихонько переминалась с ноги на
>   ногу, устраиваясь под грузом трёх объёмных сумок.

Что за служка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот человек — секундант (и помощник секунданта).

Секундант обязан иметь при себе нашатырный спирт, бинт, вату, холодную воду, назубник, полотенце, лейкопластырь, резиновую губку.
На ринге секундант помогает боксеру снять халат, освежает холодной водой зубной протектор и одевает его на зубы боксера. Перед боем секундант дает боксеру ряд практических указаний, настраивает его на победу, подбадривает.

[**Е. И. Огуренков. Современный бокс**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=Kmj-AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=uGdgRsMJ3r&sig=IeN_k8OK-fZ2u7PfAP-dLuxRio8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwismNDGyPHaAhXDzaQKHfiICwQQ6AEwBnoECAAQYA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5&f=false)

Comment: Это не о современном, а Советском ещё, т. е. любительском боксе конца 50-х гг.  Наборчик смешной, особенно назубник и резиновая губка.

Comment: Тогда, наверно, это был _современный_ бокс.  Смысл "секундантства" от времени практически не поменялся.

Comment: Я — о глубокой историчности книги и милой устаревшей информации, в ней обнаруженной.

Answer (score 1):

Есть в боксе такое понятие - секундант. У спортсмена, во время матча, он может быть не один. Тогда, среди секундантов назначается старший секундант. В интернете есть вся информация по этому поводу.